# How to find spree account view source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, spree

recently I had a need to modify a view template of the Spree e-commerce. According to the guides, I need to run `bundle show spree` to view current location of the spree gem and then copy view templates from there. https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/view.html But the target folder does not contain views folder `<< account >>`, also I did a search for particular word 'favourites', no results. Maybe I need to install other gem, like spree_frontend or other? Can someone please help to find views to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with Spree but it looks like you're supposed to write/customize your own template using Deface. There is no "account" file in the source tree. To search go to their github, click the  backend directory, click "Find file" and enter "account"... seems there are no results.

Later edit: you might want to look at these templates here:

https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/master/backend/app/views/spree/admin/users

I think one of them is used for the "account" method. If you're trying to edit the admin account edit page for instance, it's the users/edit.html.erb template.

Comment: there is a way to copy existing template to customize. I just don't know how to do

Comment: Which account page you trying to mess with? admin module users edit account page? in that case it's backend/app/views/spree/admin/users/edit.html.erb

Comment: PS: on a side note, that's what you get when you try to pull dirty hacks on sundays :)))))

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, Nick my goal is to modify view, which corresponds to the controller `account` , action 'favourites' ---> account/favourites. that's not related to editing user properties.

Comment: the right location of the account / orders and account / favourites is following spree_my_favourites/app/views. The problem was that there are many different gems, so searching for particular view is not easy. anyway, thanks for trying. [spree_my_favourites](https://github.com/frankmt/spree_my_favourites/blob/master/app/views/spree/account/favourites/index.haml)

Comment: You can always tailf the development log to see exactly what template you want to edit when you hit the page...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using devise with spree you want to look for account and auth related views to override in [spree auth devise](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise) gem views

https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/tree/master/lib/views